# How to get number of hours/minutes JSON is running

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, performance

I have a page that calls JSON API. It shows a loading image while processing. I need to check if it is more than 5 minutes running, then show an alert message. Can't find on Google. Thank you!

ADDED my code:

```
function SeeMyCoupon(list, func) {
    CallLoadingPopup(true);
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.test.com/api/SeeMyCode.ashx",
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: list,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
           if (func) {
                func(data);
                CallLoadingPopup(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the API from javascript? Or from your server? Could you show the calling code?

Comment: from js. please see the edited qn, i have added the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `timeout` property:

```
function SeeMyCoupon(list, func) {
    CallLoadingPopup(true);
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.test.com/api/SeeMyCode.ashx",
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: list,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        timeout: 300000,
        success: function (data) {
           if (func) {
                func(data);
                CallLoadingPopup(false);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if(textStatus === "timeout") {
                alert('The operation took more than 5 minutes');
        } 
    });
}
```

Also please note that setting `async: false` is a very bad design. This is not AJAX. You are blocking the client browser during the entire execution of the request. AJAX is meant to be asynchronous.